# Recursive CTE don't work when recursion predicate uses a bind variable

Tags: java, sql, h2, recursive-query

When using recursive CTE in [H2](http://www.h2database.com) (I know, experimental feature), the following query doesn't work:

```java
Connection con = getConnection();
System.out.println("Wrong result:");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "WITH recursive t(f) AS ( "+
    "    SELECT 1             "+
    "    UNION ALL            "+
    "    SELECT t.f + 1       "+
    "    FROM t               "+
    "    WHERE t.f < ?        "+
    ")                        "+
    "SELECT t.f               "+
    "FROM t                   "
);
stmt.setInt(1, 10);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next())
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
```

The produced output is:

```
1
```

The expected result would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue [(see here)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/h2-database/OJfqNF_Iqyo/brxu-Lu3c78J). H2 has problems when recursive queries contain bind variables. The following query doesn't use bind values and works as expected:

```
System.out.println("Correct result:");
rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(
    "WITH recursive t(f) AS ( "+
    "    SELECT 1             "+
    "    UNION ALL            "+
    "    SELECT t.f + 1       "+
    "    FROM t               "+
    "    WHERE t.f < 10       "+
    ")                        "+
    "SELECT t.f               "+
    "FROM t                   "
);

while (rs.next())
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
```