# Spring jdbc not work with h2 query recursion

Tags: java, spring, recursion, jdbc, h2

There are standard tables groups and ACL. I made a connection with the group table a many to many to be able to include the group in the group . Now when I try to Spring security to replace the query using the H2 database and the type of request

```
@Bean
public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager manager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
    manager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    manager.setRolePrefix("GROUP_");
    manager.setEnableGroups(true);
    manager.setEnableAuthorities(false);
    manager.setGroupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            //h2
            "WITH recursive rec_groups (parent, child, name, authority) AS " +
                    "(SELECT gm.group_id, cast(NULL as bigint), g.group_name, ga.authority " +
                    "FROM wsseddb.group_members as gm, wsseddb.groups g, wsseddb.GROUP_AUTHORITIES as ga " +
                    "WHERE username = ? and g.id = gm.group_id and ga.group_id = gm.group_id " +
                    "UNION ALL " +
                    "SELECT gpc.parent_id, gpc.child_id, g.group_name, ga.authority " +
                    "FROM wsseddb.groups_parent_child as  gpc, rec_groups as rg, wsseddb.GROUPS  as g,  wsseddb.GROUP_AUTHORITIES as ga " +
                    "WHERE child_id = rg.parent and g.id = gpc.parent_id and ga.group_id = gpc.parent_id) " +
                    "SELECT gs.parent, gs.name as group_name, gs.authority FROM rec_groups gs");
    return manager;
}`
```

I do not come back List GrandedAuthority. When I use postgresql , all works well . How to solve this problem with h2?

[image]

In web H2 query work good but in spring jdbc preparentstatement return 0 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is a known bug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h2-database/OJfqNF_Iqyo/brxu-Lu3c78J) in H2's implementation of recursive CTE. [See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32827660/521799). As it stands now (version 1.4.191), the execution is incorrect if your recursive CTE contains any bind variables. It should work if you remove and inline the bind variable (beware of SQL injection, of course).

Do note that this feature is [experimental in H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html?highlight=recursive&search=recurs#recursive_queries)

Comment: Thx Lukas! 
I 'll try a different database